# React Apollo multiple refetches not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to make these three refetches but only one is working. I have no idea what the problem is.

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
  this.props.searchEvent.refetch({ term: text })
  this.props.searchUser.refetch({ name: text })
  this.props.searchLocation.refetch({ location: text })
  this.setState({ searchTerm: text })
}}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional details. Which two queries are not being refetched? How do you know they're not being refetched -- have you looked in the Network tab to see if the requests are being fired? Are there any errors being shown in the console? It would also be good to see more of your code, including the queries themselves and how you're using the react-apollo components.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by making the callback function async.

```
onChangeText={async (text) => {

                            await this.props.searchUser.refetch({ name: text })
                            await this.props.searchEvent.refetch({ term: text })
                            await this.setState({ searchTerm: text })
                            await this.props.searchLocation.refetch({ location: text })

                        }}
```